# How to call a callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I have a JavaScript plugin which contains the following function. Currently it is working when I click on the element. But I want this function to be called from my JavaScript file.

```
this.ClickManage = function(e) {
    var id = e.id;
    console.log(li);
    return li;
};
```

I just called like this.But it is not get triggered.

```
image = new ClickEvent({
ClickManage:function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
});
```

How can I call this function from my JavaScript file?

Comment: you need be more specific and show more code... how this is tricker??

Comment: when I click on an image this function will be called.What I need is when I click on the image.I need to call my function which I defined in my custom js file.

Comment: Update the question, not the comments. If you want to call the function you need to show what `this` is. Without more code context nobody can tell you how to call it

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to trigger the element click.
If "this" is a button with id "mybutton", you can do this...

```
$('#mybutton').trigger('click')
```

Comment: sorry I can't able to do with any id's or class.When I click on an element this fuction will be called.

Comment: @user3431651 that comment doesn't make much sense. This solution does what you very vaguely asked for. Please update question with more specifics. Question is not very clear